# What is the simplest js code I would need to extend a hover display block so it remains there for a second

Tags: javascript, css, timeout, navigation, hover

What is the simplest `javascript` code I would need to extend a hover display block so it remains there for a second before reverting back to its display none state in order that the user could click the extended navigation where display none is default in css and hover reveals the block

I need only an extended timeout just some simple code

(I have a working solution in css only - instead of using display none I used max-size 1 px and zero alpha so it dosn't dissapear ever but would still like to know the javascript code)

Also is there any way in css that hover would set display block to a completely different div to the one you hovering on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you are using mouseover and mouseout events to display and hide the display block, so use a timeout to hide the block. If a mouseover event occurs before the timeout fires, cancel it. Here's a very simple example:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Lingering block</title>

  <style type="text/css">
  #foo, #bar {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
  }
  #bar {
    background-color: red;
  }
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  var uX = (function() {
    var timer;

    function showBar() {
      if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = null;
      }
      document.getElementById('bar').style.display = '';
    }

    function hideBar() {
      timer = setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById('bar').style.display = 'none';
      },1000);
    }

    return {
      init: function() {
        var bar = document.getElementById('bar');
        var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
        foo.onmouseover = showBar;
        foo.onmouseout = hideBar;
        bar.onmouseover = showBar;
        bar.onmouseout = hideBar;
        bar.style.display = 'none';
        foo = null;
        bar = null;
      }
    };
  }());

  window.onload = uX.init;

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="foo"></div>
    <div id="bar"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

A production version should use event delegation and not hard-code things, the above is just a demonstration of the strategy.

Comment: looks good,How do I use both the javascript and the css if I were lets say  #bar was <ul> <li> /> nested in #foo and #foo:hover li would display block to show the list and normal #foo li would display none

Comment: If the ui is a descendant of foo, then put listeners on foo only as mouseover/out will bubble. Consider adding/removing classes instead of setting display directly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you've nearly answered yourself. If you have a "solution" in CSS already just use Javascript to revert that setting.

Something like:

onMouseOver = setInterval("this.style.opacity = 0", 1000);

This (untested psuedocode) will set the opacity to 0 after a second (1000 ms).

You could obviously get trickier - you'll probably want to reset the CSS back to normal onMouseOut.  But basically, just reverse the CSS you've found dynamically using script.

I could be missing something of course.

Comment: You probably want to use setTimeout instead of setInterval

Comment: Absolutely... brain fart on my part.  You can then set another timeout - firing a few ms after that - to reset the property back to the original value.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should have a look at [JQUERY UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/show/). I think it will serve your purpose and you also could have a look into the script of Jquery ui to know what is happening inside the javascript....